# Expand a comma separated item in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two python lists of the following form:

```
grocery_list = ["apple", "whole milk, skim milk, 2% milk", "american cheese, cheddar cheese"]
grocery_cost = [10.5, 4.50, 2.40]
```

and I would like to convert them to a more easily read from list of the form:

```
grocery_list = ["apple", "whole milk" , "skim milk", "2% milk", "american cheese", "cheddar cheese"]
grocery_cost = [10.5, 4.50, 4.50, 4.50, 2.40, 2.40]
```

Essentially I have a series of lists where certain indexes are themselves comma separated lists.

Comment: And how would we know which price belongs to which product? Right now it's just guesswork. Are "milk" items worth 4.50, and "cheese" items 2.40?

Comment: The grocery_list list contains only 3 values, the second index contains a comma separated list. The cost of all the items in the second index are the same.

Comment: I see now that the commas are sometimes present within a string. Would have been more clear if it was specified more in the question.

Comment: Do you want to use other packages such as pandas or simply the python standard library?

Comment: I am up to use any package, whatever makes it easiest to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to iterate through the original grocery and pice together, split grocery by comma (assuming that comma is always the separator), and repeat the price the same number of times as the length of the grocery list after the split.

The sample code is shown below.

```py
grocery_list = ["apple", "whole milk, skim milk, 2% milk", "american cheese, cheddar cheese"]
grocery_cost = [10.5, 4.50, 2.40]

updated_grocery_list = []
updated_grocery_cost = []
for g, c in zip(grocery_list, grocery_cost):
    g_list = [gg.strip() for gg in g.split(",")]  # split on comma and remove spaces
    updated_grocery_list.extend(g_list)
    updated_grocery_cost.extend([c] * len(g_list))

print(updated_grocery_list)
print(updated_grocery_cost)

# Output
# ['apple', 'whole milk', 'skim milk', '2% milk', 'american cheese', 'cheddar cheese']
# [10.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 2.4, 2.4]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally just create a dictionary from the two lists so you don't have to use indices to get the matching price and items as such:

```py
grocery_list = ["apple", "whole milk, skim milk, 2% milk", "american cheese, cheddar cheese"]
grocery_cost = [10.5, 4.50, 2.40]

grocery_dict = {product: cost for product_item, cost in zip(grocery_list, grocery_cost) for product in product_item.split(',')}

print(grocery_dict)
```

Output:

```py
{'apple': 10.5, 'whole milk': 4.5, ' skim milk': 4.5, ' 2% milk': 4.5, 'american cheese': 2.4, ' cheddar cheese': 2.4}
```

This way, you can look up the price by simply using `grocery_dict['whole milk']`, for example.